# TinyMCE - Uncaught TypeError: wc[0].removeClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

[This TinyMCE plugin](https://github.com/slimeygecko/wordcount-maxlength) is forked from the wordcount plugin to also display error message when character count is past set limit. But it is not working. On every update action `addClass` and `removeClass` functions can't be found. I've slightly edited the code but the core is the same:

```
// on init
var statusbar = editor.theme.panel && editor.theme.panel.find('#statusbar')[0];
if (statusbar) {
    tinymce.util.Delay.setEditorTimeout(editor, function() {
        statusbar.insert({
            type: 'label',
            name: 'maxlength',
            text: ['Length: {0}', self.getCharCount()],
            classes: 'wordcount',
            disabled: editor.settings.readonly
        }, 0);
...
// on update
var wc = editor.theme.panel.find('#maxlength');
wc[0].removeClass('danger');  // Error!
```

How to fix it?

**EDIT:** `console.log(wc[0])` output:

```
t {_super: undefined, settings: Object, _id: "mceu_160", _aria: Object, _elmCache: Object…}
  $: function f(e,t)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context...]
    attrHooks: Object
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context...]
    contains: function (e,t)
    cssHooks: Object
    each: function m(e,t)
    expr: Object
    extend: function s(e,n)
    filter: function (e,t,n)
    find: function e(e,t,n,r)
    fn: f[0]
    grep: function g(e,t)
    inArray: function h(e,t)
    isArray: function isArray()
    length: 2
    makeArray: function (e)
    name: "f"
    overrideDefaults: function (e)
    prototype: f[0]
    text: function (e)
    trim: function p(e)
    unique: function (e)
    __proto__: function ()
    <function scope>
  $el: f.fn.f.init[1]
  _aria: Object
  _elmCache: Object
  _eventDispatcher: t
  _eventsRoot: t
  _id: "mceu_160"
  _name: "wordcount"
  _nativeEvents: Object
  _parent: t
  _super: undefined
  borderBox: undefined
  canFocus: false
  classes: n
  data: t
  marginBox: undefined
  paddingBox: undefined
  rootControl: t
  settings: Object
  state: t
  type: "label"
  __proto__: t
```

Comment: is editor.theme.panel.find('#maxlength') a valid dom element?

Comment: Trying logging the wc variable and seeing what it contains. Other than that, make sure that jQuery is properly loaded :)

Comment: @Thariama yes, it is.

Comment: @Ynhockey, please see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the delete answer contains the key to this.

`wc[0]` holds a valid dom element, but `removeClasse` is not a valid function you may call on such an element (at least without the use of jQuery).

Without jQuery you may try the following:

Instead of calling `removeClass` use

```
wc[0].setAttribute('class', '');
```

Instead of calling `addClass` use

```
wc[0].setAttribute('class', 'danger');
```

This is a bit simplified, but in case you are not using any other classes in the `wc[0]` element it should be fine.

Comment: The same error: `wc[0].setAttribute is not a function`

Comment: hmm, can you show me exactly the spot where you try to execute the code (you say 'onInit', but what does that mean)?

Comment: Please, refer to these [sources](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slimeygecko/wordcount-maxlength/master/wordcountmaxlength.js) - there is `addClass` / `removeClass` methods inside `update()`; `update()` is executed on `keyup` and on `setcontent beforeaddundo` TinyMCE events.

Comment: well, that looks perfectly fine. where did you call console.log(wc[0]);

Comment: In Chrome's JS console; I've placed a breakpoint after `var wc` initialization and called `console.log(wc[0]);`

Comment: wierd, addClass and removeClass shoulb be there after initialization